# Laravel 7 Docker - Unable to Login to Application

Tags: php, laravel, docker, authentication, docker-compose

I have 2 dockerized laravel apps, which were working fine previously (about 2 months back), now when i try to login to them, App is unable to authenticate.
When i use unauthenticated routes, app works fine.
Database is working fine. Migrations , seeding is working too.
Another laravel app is working absolutely fine with same Dockerfile settings.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

USER root

# WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'geninv'
    container_name: geninv
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks: 
      default:

networks: 
  default:
    external: 
      name: mynet
```

I am using mysql 8 with external volume on **mynet** network
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very odd overlook by me. Simple

```
php artisan config:cache
```

re created the cache and every thing went smooth after it.